# Pausing/Resuming A Game Thread Using wait() and notify() - Android

Tags: android, wait, notify

I have a main game thread but when the target score is achieved I have an activity that is launched called StageCleared which basically displays the stats to the user of their performance and then they can press a continue button to carry on with the game. This should switch focus back to the running thread that should continue execution, and thus display the game activity (with parameters i update after StageCleared has exectued).

It was suggested I use a package visible object that calls wait() on itself in the main game thread, and then notify() on itself from StageCleared in order to continue execution. My first problem is I can't seem to declare a package visible object that can be seen by all the classes in my package? Secondly, is this the best way to achieve what I'm intending to do or is there a better way?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

To enable package visibile, leave the modifier blank:

```
static boolean mVarname = true;
```

mVarname is visible inside the package.

I work with a run flag to enable if the loop should do something or just "idle". I, too, dont know if this is a good way to do it :)

Comment: Thanks, I thought that was how but it still doesn't like it. At the moment what I'm trying is an Object that I pass a reference to in a method called on a variable of type StageCleared. I will see if that can solve it. It's an obscure way of using the same object but you have to love pointers in cases like this.

Comment: Using synchronized with the thread as an argument is the answer I think from my noodling around, it has solved the problem of an IllegalMonitorStateException. Perhaps that will come in handy for you too if ever you need it!

Answer (score 0):

Use FutureTask and Executor, check it out in Java API.

It's like, you define the operation and FutureTask, and it'll wait until the task is completed.
Easier than wait()